# php sees, for example, 11 as 1

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

```
function zwrot() {
   var zwrot = document.getElementsByClassName("zwroc");
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < zwrot.length; i++) {
      if(zwrot[i].checked){
        parseInt(zwrot[i])
        var ajax = $.ajax({
            url: 'php/request.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {zwrot: zwrot[i].value},
            success: function(data)
            {
               $.growl.notice({ 
                    title: "INFO", 
                    message: "Oddano książkę" });
            }
        })
      }
   }
   setTimeout(function() { 
                  location.reload()
              }, 2000
   );
}
```

php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['zwrot'])) { 
      $zwrot=$_POST['zwrot']; 
      $n = count($zwrot); 
      for ($i=0;$i<$n; $i++){ 
           $data=date("d-m-Y"); 
           $zapytanie5 = mysqli_query ($link, "UPDATE zamowienie SET data_zwrotu='$data' WHERE id_zamowienie=$zwrot[$i]"); 
           $zapytanie6 = mysqli_query ($link, "UPDATE ksiazka INNER JOIN zamowienie ON ksiazka.id_ksiazka=zamowienie.id_ksiazka SET ilosc=ilosc+1 WHERE id_zamowienie=$zwrot[$i];");
      }
}
```

everything is ok, until id is a one-digit number. the problem occurs with two-digit numbers, php sees, for example, 11 as 1

Comment: `until id is a one-digit number` What is `id`? There is no `id` in your code

Comment: _"php sees"_ - but we don't see any php!?

Comment: sry, i mean var zwrot = document.getElementsByClassName("zwroc"); this is getting value from my table, my fault not id

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['zwrot'])) {
  $zwrot=$_POST['zwrot'];
  $n = count($zwrot);
  for ($i=0;$i<$n; $i++){
  $data=date("d-m-Y");
        $zapytanie5 = mysqli_query ($link, "UPDATE zamowienie SET data_zwrotu='$data' WHERE id_zamowienie=$zwrot[$i]");
$zapytanie6 = mysqli_query ($link, "UPDATE ksiazka INNER JOIN zamowienie ON ksiazka.id_ksiazka=zamowienie.id_ksiazka SET ilosc=ilosc+1 WHERE id_zamowienie=$zwrot[$i];");}}`

Comment: did you check what `$zrot` in php actually is? _Hint:_ It's not an array. You are doing a seperate ajax call for each element with classname 'szroc'.

Comment: i don't know how to say it, my english is bad, but in my opinion that is an array, if send 9 records in that function to php, all works, but it must be number<10

Comment: i sugges use prepared statements

Comment: that function is to returning books and it is ok when i can return several at once, example if i have 9 inputs with value from 1 to 9 and i checked all of them, function is ok, 9 books will be returned, but if i want to return book with value=10 to 19, always will be returned book with value 1, from 20 to 29 returned book with value 2 and etc

Comment: @lysekk `$zwrot` is not an array because you specifically send only a single value in your JS: `data: {zwrot: zwrot[i].value}`

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you're passing any array to your php. and that's not how you pass and receive an array through ajax if ever, you need json for that.

Anyway, try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['zwrot'])) { 

    $zwrot=$_POST['zwrot']; 

    $data=date("d-m-Y"); 
    $zapytanie5 = mysqli_query ($link, "UPDATE zamowienie SET data_zwrotu='$data' WHERE id_zamowienie=$zwrot"); 
    $zapytanie6 = mysqli_query ($link, "UPDATE ksiazka INNER JOIN zamowienie ON ksiazka.id_ksiazka=zamowienie.id_ksiazka SET ilosc=ilosc+1 WHERE id_zamowienie=$zwrot;");

}
```

Or if you want to pass by array:

```
function zwrot() {
   var zwrot = document.getElementsByClassName("zwroc");
   var i;

   var zwrot_array = [];

   for (i = 0; i < zwrot.length; i++) {
      if(zwrot[i].checked){
        zwrot_array[i] = zwrot[i].value;
      }
   }

   var ajax = $.ajax({
        url: 'php/request.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {zwrot: JSON.stringify(zwrot_array)},
        success: function(data)
        {
           $.growl.notice({ 
                title: "INFO", 
                message: "Oddano książkę" 
            });

            setTimeout(function() { 
                  location.reload()
              }, 2000
           );
        }
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['zwrot'])) { 

    $zwrots = json_decode($_POST['zwrot']); 
    $data=date("d-m-Y"); 

    foreach ($zwrots as $zwrot) {
        $zapytanie5 = mysqli_query ($link, "UPDATE zamowienie SET data_zwrotu='$data' WHERE id_zamowienie=$zwrot"); 
        $zapytanie6 = mysqli_query ($link, "UPDATE ksiazka INNER JOIN zamowienie ON ksiazka.id_ksiazka=zamowienie.id_ksiazka SET ilosc=ilosc+1 WHERE id_zamowienie=$zwrot;");
    }
}
```